# Copy only last file in series in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

If I have a series of files formatted like:

```
file_name_1.dat
file_name_2.dat
...
file_name_37.dat
file_name_38.dat
file_name_39.dat
```

is there a one-liner to copy the last (highest number) file in the series to a file called `last.dat`? The numbers are always sequential positive integers.

Comment: If you are using ls to display the files you can use `ls -v` to list in numerical order.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible solutions using arrays. If the list of files is consecutive, you only need to know how many there are to find the last index.

```
files=( file_name_*.dat )
num_files="${#files[@]}"
```

Here, even though the array ordering itself doesn't help, just knowing how many files there are tells you what the number of the last file should be. `"file_name_${num_files}.dat"` should exist.

If they are not consecutive, remember that bash arrays are sparse, but ordered, and just turn the file numbers into array indices directly:

```
x=()
for f in file_name_*; do
    i="${f#file_name_}"
    i="${i%.dat}"
    x[$i]="$f"
done
indices=( "${!x[@]}" )
last_index="${indices[@]: -1}"
last_file_numerically="${x[last_index]}"
```

Really, the last file numerically is already `"${x[@]: -1}"`, but I used direct manipulation of the indices to show what's going on.

Update: Etan suggests that we not keep all the files in a mostly-unused array. That approach also means we can write a POSIXly-strict solution, where sh doesn't have arrays.

```
max=0
max_file=
for f in file_name_*; do
    i="${f#file_name}"
    i="${i%.dat}"
    if [ $i -gt $max ]; then
        max=$i
        max_file="$f"
    fi
done
```

Here, `max_file` should hold the filename of the numerically* last file.

*The [POSIX test utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) actually says its comparisons are *algebraic*, not *numeric*. You're welcome to argue the distinction. ;)

Comment: The first version doesn't work with these file names because the glob sort is alphabetic and not human/natural-numeric (i.e. `file_name_10.dat` will sort before `file_name_2.dat` in glob ordering).

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, but the _index_ will be the count of the files, so a file named "file_name_${last_index}.dat" would exist under those (admittedly limited) circumstances. The second solution is far more general, though.

Comment: The second solution works though but the use of the array is not necessary since once you are looping manually you might as well just keep a max value and the filename that goes with it but *shrug*.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing there. Yes, assuming contiguous integers that first solution works by just getting the count. Clever.

Comment: @EtanReisner updated. It's true that the second answer could track the max index, but the array there is actually numerically ordered, so the last element of that array is actually the correct answer.

Comment: My point about the second snippet wasn't to keep the max index and then use that to get the value from the array but rather that if you are looping manually over the numbers then you don't need the array at all since just keeping two variables (e.g. `max` and `filename`) lets you do the comparisons manually and avoid storing entries that don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do it. Assuming the list is a file of course.

```
cp `tail -1 yourlist.list` last.dat
```

If you need to get it from `ls`:

```
cp `ls -1 | sort -t_ -f3 -n| tail -1` last.dat
```

Comment: `ls -1` will not sort the files by that number!

Comment: No. `ls` by default sorts alphanumerically. `-1` gives you "1 entry per line" and therefore is appropriate for `tail`.

Comment: Having said that - it'll sort `47` above `5` so a sort is appropriate.

Comment: @hek2mgl You can just use `ls -v`

Comment: @Sobrique Try `mkdir test; cd test; touch {1,11,22,2}.dat; ls -1` `2.dat` comes after `22`. But `ls -v1` looks indeed appropriate.

Comment: Yes. That's because alphanumerically, `2.` is before `22`. `ls -1`.

Comment: Your answer should reflect that, isn't it?

Comment: My answer has a `sort` in it now, and has for a while.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a meeting. Looks good now! :) But you could suggest `-v1` since it is shorter and does the same. However, I'm not sure how portable it is.

Comment: `-v` is relatively new as an option and you don't need `-1` here at all when piped `ls` is line-oriented by default (and I'm not even sure you can force it to use columns). That being said the output from `ls` isn't reliable and [shouldn't be parsed](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) so any solution that involves it is unreliable and not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the last (highest number) file in the series to a file called last.dat:

```
cp `sort -t_ -k 3 -n filename | tail -1` last.dat
```

`sort` will first sort the file `filename`. This will help if the file names are not sorted. Sorting the file will bring the highest number file to the last.

Comment: @Sobrique That's what the arguments to `sort` are ensuring. `-t` sets the field separator to `_`. `-k` sets the key field to sort from field 3 to the end. and `-n` says to sort numerically.

Comment: `filename` in the sort isn't useful here as the entries to sort are the files in the directory and for safety the result of the command substitution should be quoted. Also using `$(...)` is preferable to using backticks.